# Detect process exit on OSX

Tags: c, macos

I want to be notified right before a process exits on OSX so that I can gather statistics about the process before it dies.  (Example specifics: I want to aggregate CPU usage for processes that have many child processes that spawn and die quickly, but use large amounts of CPU.  When sampling CPU usage via things like `proc_pidinfo`, processes that are born and die at rates similar to my sampling rate do not get adequately captured in my aggregate statistics.  I would like to be notified when processes die so that I can sum up their total user and system time.

So far, the approach that has seemed like it will work the best has been to use `libdtrace`, but I can't figure out how to set a probe for process exit using the `dtrace` command, much less set up `libdtrace` from a C program.  Any tips on setting such a dtrace probe as well as tutorials on how to use `libdtrace` would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Alright, following the advice of a few commenters, I have managed to create a program that uses libdtrace and reliably triggers off of a process' exit.  This is great, but unfortunately I can't seem to get the PID of the process that is exiting.  It seems that calling `printf()` in my D program and trying to format integers is badly broken.  Specifically, if I run [this program](https://gist.github.com/staticfloat/f2d29c9cbd6386788ec0) which is supposed to print out the name and PID of a process right as it's exiting, it fails miserably.  It prints some other integer, and indeed that integer is printed no matter what I try to output.  If I change the D program from

```
syscall::*exit*:entry {
    printf(\"%s %d\\n\", execname, curpsinfo->pr_pid);
};
```

To just

```
syscall::*exit*:entry {
    printf(\"%d\\n\", 100);
};
```

It just prints out the first three digits of the mystery integer.  Note that the process names are correct, it's just the integer -> string conversion that is failing, I believe.  Running the main `dtrace` program with the above D programs works properly, but I want to integrate this into a C program that I have already written a lot into, and piping subcommand outputs into that program isn't really the way I want to move forward.

Help on how to get either the buffered output from `libdtrace` to work properly, or alternatively to get the PID as an integer rather than a string would be great.

Comment: I don't know about `libdtrace`, but you can use the following `dtrace` command to monitor process exit: `sudo dtrace -n 'proc:::exit { trace(pid); trace(execname); }'`.

Comment: I believe the above only fires after the process has exited. If you want to catch it while it's exiting, you can use the probe `syscall::*exit*:entry`. To stop a process there, you have to allow "destructive" actions with the `-w` option to `dtrace` and use the `stop()` action in the probe body: `sudo dtrace -w -n 'syscall::*exit*:entry { stop(); }`. You can then examine the process at your leisure. To let the process resume, you have to use the `pidresume()` action: `sudo dtrace -w -n 'BEGIN { pidresume($pid); }` -p <the PID>`.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is actually pretty much exactly what I want!  The only problem now is in using libdtrace.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is an Apple technical note for this subject.

[TN2050 Observing Process Lifetimes Without Polling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2050/_index.html)

For monitoring an arbitrary process, this guide suggests `kqueues`.

We can obtain PIDs of running processes by this way [[unable to detect application running with another user (via switch user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820199/unable-to-detect-application-running-with-another-user-via-switch-user/18821357#18821357]) or this way [[Programmatically check if a process is running on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518160/programmatically-check-if-a-process-is-running-on-mac]).

**Listing 8  Using kqueues to monitor a specific process**

```
static pid_t gTargetPID = -1;
    // We assume that some other code sets up gTargetPID.

- (IBAction)testNoteExit:(id)sender
{
    FILE *                  f;
    int                     kq;
    struct kevent           changes;
    CFFileDescriptorContext context = { 0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL };
    CFRunLoopSourceRef      rls;

    // Create the kqueue and set it up to watch for SIGCHLD. Use the 
    // new-in-10.5 EV_RECEIPT flag to ensure that we get what we expect.

    kq = kqueue();

    EV_SET(&changes, gTargetPID, EVFILT_PROC, EV_ADD | EV_RECEIPT, NOTE_EXIT, 0, NULL);
    (void) kevent(kq, &changes, 1, &changes, 1, NULL);

    // Wrap the kqueue in a CFFileDescriptor (new in Mac OS X 10.5!). Then 
    // create a run-loop source from the CFFileDescriptor and add that to the 
    // runloop.

    noteExitKQueueRef = CFFileDescriptorCreate(NULL, kq, true, NoteExitKQueueCallback, &context);
    rls = CFFileDescriptorCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, noteExitKQueueRef, 0);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), rls, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    CFRelease(rls);

    CFFileDescriptorEnableCallBacks(noteExitKQueueRef, kCFFileDescriptorReadCallBack);

    // Execution continues in NoteExitKQueueCallback, below.
}

static void NoteExitKQueueCallback(
    CFFileDescriptorRef f, 
    CFOptionFlags       callBackTypes, 
    void *              info
)
{
    struct kevent   event;

    (void) kevent( CFFileDescriptorGetNativeDescriptor(f), NULL, 0, &event, 1, NULL);

    NSLog(@"terminated %d", (int) (pid_t) event.ident);

    // You've been notified!
}
```

Comment: This does indeed notify me right after a process has exited, but by the time the process has exited, I can't get the information I need from it!  Thanks for putting me onto kqueues though, very neat!

Answer (score 0):

[The following example takes a UNIX process ID as argument, and watches up to 20 seconds, and reports if the process terminates in that time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cffiledescriptor-ru3#2556086)

```
// cc test.c -framework CoreFoundation -O
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/event.h>
static void noteProcDeath(CFFileDescriptorRef fdref, CFOptionFlags callBackTypes, void *info) {
    struct kevent kev;
    int fd = CFFileDescriptorGetNativeDescriptor(fdref);
    kevent(fd, NULL, 0, &kev, 1, NULL);
    // take action on death of process here
    printf("process with pid '%u' died\n", (unsigned int)kev.ident);
    CFFileDescriptorInvalidate(fdref);
    CFRelease(fdref); // the CFFileDescriptorRef is no longer of any use in this example
}
// one argument, an integer pid to watch, required
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) exit(1);
    int fd = kqueue();
    struct kevent kev;
    EV_SET(&kev, atoi(argv[1]), EVFILT_PROC, EV_ADD|EV_ENABLE, NOTE_EXIT, 0, NULL);
    kevent(fd, &kev, 1, NULL, 0, NULL);
    CFFileDescriptorRef fdref = CFFileDescriptorCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, fd, true, noteProcDeath, NULL);
    CFFileDescriptorEnableCallBacks(fdref, kCFFileDescriptorReadCallBack);
    CFRunLoopSourceRef source = CFFileDescriptorCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, fdref, 0);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetMain(), source, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    CFRelease(source);
    // run the run loop for 20 seconds
    CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 20.0, false);
    return 0;
}
```

For those who barely know C:
build: `cc test.c -framework CoreFoundation -O`
run: `./a.out 57168`
57168 is the pid of the process being monitored. Kill it to test!

Surely you can increase the 20 seconds to make it last as long as you want.

Comment: OP's comment on 9dan's answer explains why `kqueue` is not sufficient for their purpose.